# I cannot make spaces in RStudio / space key does not work

Tags: rstudio

**I have a problem with RStudio: I cannot make spaces in RStudio or the space key does not work. The problem does not occur with the R program or with any other program on my computer, only with RStudio.

Instead of a space, it sometimes jumps back and forth between windows when the space key is pressed.

Here are the key data of my computer and an example of the problem as screenshot
...(see screenshot line #wirdüberschrieben#labelsBESSERziegtNICHTgewählteAUSPRÄGUNGEN-> I could not write it with spaces):

MacBook Pro (14", 2021)

macOS Monterey 12.0.1

R 4.1.3

Keyboard Language: German

Does anyone know the bug or how to fix it?

Thx in advance!!!

Bildschirmfoto 2022-04-11 um 12.00.22
Bildschirmfoto 2022-04-11 um 12.00.22
1500×114 29 KB

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already found the solution after such a long while? This is not an RStudio issue. Try this: Go to "System preferences" > "Accessibility" > on the left, scroll down to "Keyboard" > untick "Enable Full Keyboard access".